# Using python 'requests' to send JSON boolean

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I've got a really simple question, but I can't figure it out how to do it. The problem I have is that I want to send the following payload using Python and Requests:

```
{ 'on': true }
```

Doing it like this:

```
payload = { 'on':true }
r = requests.put("http://192.168.2.196/api/newdeveloper/lights/1/state", data = payload)
```

Doesn't work, because I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Sending the *true* as *'true'* is not accepted by my server, so that's not an option. Anyone a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: `True` on python is spelt with a capital 'T' :)

Comment: Uhm, it's `True` in Python...

Comment: I know that it's True. But when I put 'True' there, the payload will be "{'on': True}". I want it to be "{'on': true}"

Comment: You need to json encode it to get it to a string. `import json` `payload = json.dumps({"on":True})`

Comment: can boolean data be send over GET params?
I tried using python-requests, but Other side I am receiving string data.
I want to pass some some boolean (true/false) data.

Comment: @OmPrakash GET data has to be a string yes, it's just part of the URL. if you are using json you can just use `json.loads(data)` to convert it back on the server, or whichever appropriate deserialisation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to json encode it to get it to a string.

```
import json 
payload = json.dumps({"on":True})
```

Comment: doesn't this still give out "on" and "True" ?

Answer (score 6):

should be {'on': True}, capital T

Comment: That doesn't work. I want the payload to be {'on':true}. This will turn the payload into {'on':True}, which unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: that is because you need to dump the dictionary using json. For example, when you have payload={"on": True}, do json.dumps(payload)

Comment: Passing a proper Boolean object helped us ie True / False

Answer (score 6):

Starting from requests 2.4.2, instead of passing in the payload with the `data` parameter, you can use the [`json` parameter](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) like this:

```py
payload = {'on': True}
requests.put(url, json=payload)
```

And the request will be formatted correctly as a json payload (i.e. `{'on': true}`).

Answer (score 1):

to make it be lower case like that (if that's what your endpoint requires) do in quotes {'on':'true'}